# Несколько доменов

Tags: python, django

Необходимо чтобы по поддомену выполнялся своё приложение.

Есть site.com, нужно чтобы по main.site.con вызывалось приложение 'apps.views.main'

Попробовал сделать это через middleware:

```
class SomeDomainMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
         if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] == 'main.site.con':
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
         else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Пробовал через `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apps.views.main'))`, но ругается что не передал `args` и `kwargs`, хотя кроме request там ничего и не нужно.

Пробовал на уровне lighttpd разделить поддомен, но тут тоже проблема, спрашивал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165188/redirect-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B2-lighttpd), но увы никто не помог.

P.S. не хочется через SITE_ID делать это, так как по сути сайт один, просто приложение такое себе на поддомене.

Answer (score 2):

По перебирал варианты, найдя точки остановок, вывел такой код:

```
class SomeDomainMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
         if request.META['HTTP_HOST'] == 'main.site.com':
            if request.META['REQUEST_URI'] == '/':
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
         else:
             if request.META['REDIRECT_STATUS'] != '200':
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Конструкции **request.META['REDIRECT_STATUS'] != '200'** и **if request.META['REQUEST_URI'] != '/main/'** нужны, чтобы были точки остановки, без них редирект будет бесконечным, а точнее то ограниченное чисто рас, сколько сервер разрешит, после чего будет выдано - ничего, как-то так. А эти ограничения говорят нам что редирект уже был и нужно пропустить редирект.

Если кто-то имеет элегантнее способ, прошу все же поделится, так как понимаю что мой способ похож на грабли, хотя имеет место на жизнь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно на поддомен положить свой .wsgi, который будет сразу запускать Ваше приложение.

Если нужна какая-то интеграция с основным сайтом, то в .wsgi можно указать другой файл settings, например, subdomain_settings.py, в который импортировать основные settings:

```
from settings import *
```

А затем перекрыть требуемые элементы, например:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ANOTHER_DB',
        'USER': 'ANOTHER_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'ANOTHER_PASS',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        }
    }

    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/media'
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```